# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: android, flutter, widget

I am getting the above error (question) with the following code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('DeliMeals')),
  body: GridView(
    children: DUMMY_CATEGORIES
        .map((categoryData) => CategoryItem(   //getting
              categoryData.title,             //the error
              categoryData.color,            //here
            ))
        .toList(),
```

dummy_data

```
const DUMMY_CATEGORIES = const [
Category(
id: 'c1',
title: 'Italian',
color: Colors.purple,
),
Category(
id: 'c2',
title: 'Quick & Easy',
color: Colors.red,
),
];
```

I am just following a tutorial. The instructor did not get the error. :(

Comment: please share CategoryItem Code too

Comment: change `.map` to `.map<Widget>`. Please use the search next time, this has been asked a lot of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify the type of the map `map<Widget>`

```
DUMMY_CATEGORIES
        .map<Widget>((categoryData) => CategoryItem(   
              categoryData.title,             
              categoryData.color,            
            ))
        .toList(),
```